# Apache Arrow R package || Error in dplyr verbs

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I am trying to run Apache Arrow using Dplyr verbs -

In Sample code, I am getting following error, Anyone tried Apache Arrow R package with Dplyr verbs????

```r
    arrow_table(starwars) %>% 
      filter(species == "Human") %>% 
        mutate(height_ft = height/30.48) %>% 
          select(name, height_ft) %>% collect()

    Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
    > rlang::last_trace()
    <error/rlib_error_dots_nonempty>
    Error in `eval_select()`:
    ! `...` must be empty.
    x Problematic argument:
    * error_call = error_call
    ---
    Backtrace:
         x
      1. +-... %>% collect()
      2. +-dplyr::collect(.)
      3. +-dplyr::select(., name, height_ft)
      4. +-dplyr::mutate(., height_ft = height/30.48)
      5. +-dplyr::filter(., species == "Human")
      6. \-arrow:::filter.ArrowTabular(., species == "Human")
      7.   \-arrow:::compute_by(...)
      8.     \-arrow:::eval_select_by(by, data, error_call = error_call)
      9.       \-tidyselect::eval_select(expr = by, data = sim_df, allow_rename = FALSE, error_call = error_call)
     10.         \-ellipsis::check_dots_empty()
     11.           \-rlang:::action_dots(...)
     12.             +-base (local) try_dots(...)
     13.             \-rlang (local) action(...)
```

Please find below session information for your reference -

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] arrow_13.0.0.1 dplyr_1.0.10  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_0.5.0      tzdb_0.1.2       assertthat_0.2.1
 [4] utf8_1.2.2       crayon_1.4.1     R6_2.5.1        
 [7] DBI_1.1.1        lifecycle_1.0.3  magrittr_2.0.1  
[10] pillar_1.6.2     rlang_1.0.6      cli_3.6.0       
[13] rstudioapi_0.13  vctrs_0.5.2      generics_0.1.0  
[16] ellipsis_0.3.2   tools_4.1.0      bit64_4.0.5     
[19] glue_1.6.2       bit_4.0.4        purrr_1.0.1     
[22] compiler_4.1.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3  tidyselect_1.1.1
[25] tibble_3.1.3
```

Has anyone faced such situation before? Any thought to fix this as I am new to Arrow package & their Dplyr verbs?

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: Your text sample code is a parsing error, it seems unlikely that it is what you are really using.

Comment: Added More info. to dig out.

Comment: Thanks for replacing the pic. Your code is still a parsing problem, though, looks like there is one-too-many close-paren. Since the error you get has nothing to do with the parsing error, it makes it much harder to diagnose the real issue when we do not see actual code that you've used. I suspect that you are simplifying your code, which is great! But please test your simplified code before posting to make sure that it (1) reproduces the original problem, and (2) does not add other unrelated problems.

Comment: Let me take simple code to run Arrow code .

Comment: BTW, this is a much better setup, thank you for updating your question. Unfortunately, this code works for me without error, suggesting that something else is wrong. The fact that all four verbs appear to be `dplyr::` is not conclusive, at least for verification please confirm that `environment(select)` (and same for `mutate`, `filter`) returns `<environment: namespace:dplyr>`. If all do, then nothing definitive except some troubleshooting techniques: in a new R fresh (no other libraries/code) session, try the above code, report if it works differently.

Comment: Also, please include the output from `sessionInfo()` to see what other packages might be interfering.

Comment: Just to summarize issue here. I was using latest Cran version of Arrow package which was v13.0.0.1 where I was getting this error. My colleague was using Arrow v8.0.0 & he ran same code & it worked for him. It was NOT system issue. It was package version issue. I see in recent v13.0.01, dplyr::filter() giving this error whereas in v8.0.0 it's working fine.  When I see Changelog from v8.0.0, I see most of changes in Dplyr verbs. I am planning to post this issue to Maintainer for Arrow package. A Big Thank you for all for taking time to look into this.

Comment: I see you're using dplyr_1.0, are you able to upgrade that (1.1.3 is current) and try again? Nice wrap-up comment, btw. (Similar for R-4.1 to R-4.3.1.)